# Integrating Facebook and LinkedIn in Android app

Tags: android, facebook, linkedin-api, single-instance

I have an app that integrates both Facebook and LinkdedIn networks. According to the instructions, in order to integrate LinkedIn, I need to add the following code in my manifest, within my activity:

```
<intent-filter>
   <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
   <data android:scheme="x-oauthflow-linkedin" android:host="callback" />
</intent-filter>
```

An example can also be found [here](https://github.com/alt236/LinkedIn-J-Test-Application---Android/blob/master/AndroidManifest.xml). As you can see in the link, we need to add also the " **android:launchMode="singleInstance"** " line, otherwise after logging in with LinkedIn a new instance of the activity will be started.

However, when trying to log in to Facebook from the same activity, this actual line results to the following error from the Facebook Login activity (!):

**E/AndroidRuntime(7100): Caused by: com.facebook.FacebookException: Cannot call LoginActivity with a null calling package. This can occur if the launchMode of the caller is singleInstance.**

So now, I'm somehow stuck, because removing **android:launchMode="singleInstance"** will make Facebook login working, but will cause the LinkedIn login to start another instance of my activity, but if I add it, then Facebook login is not working!

Does anyone have any idea how to address this issue?

Thank you,

Dimitris

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After reading little bit on the documentation, it seems that replacing the singleInstance with singleTask did the trick. Although, I haven't figured out exactly why, I am posting this for others to see it in case someone needs it. I'll try to dig further and understand why, but in the mean time if anyone can explain why this is working, it would be nice.

Comment: Seems to be quite straightforward:

From the docs - singleInstance: "Same as "singleTask", except that the system doesn't launch any other activities into the task holding the instance."

com.facebook.LoginActivity seems to be one of those "other activities" singleInstance is prohibiting :)

More: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode

Comment: The above answer also works for conflicting requirements of integrating Facebook and Twitter: singleTask did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://code.google.com/p/socialauth-android/) sdk can integrate you to handle both facebook and linkedin without any hassle. Also use valid url for linkedin callback.

Comment: Thanks for the info user1722283. I am aware of the socialauth-android library, actually I have used it successfully in the past. But I was still trying to understand why this is happening.

Comment: There is difference between singleinstance and singletask. Singleinstance will use only one instance in android stack whereas singletask will ensure that multiple instance should not be created. so the result you are geeting currently is right. use singletask and it should solve your issue. Also if you feel it solves your issue accept the answer , it will increase your reputation on stackoverflow and you will get more help.